# how can i transfer to section of another page after submit form data?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to send my form data to another page by POST method so that be load focuse other page in my specify section. How can i do it?

```html
    <form method="post" id="loginForm" action="/index.php">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label class="labelShadow">User Name: </label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="uName" class="loginBox" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['uName']))echo $_COOKIE['uName']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label class="labelShadow">Password: </label></td>
          <td><input type="password" name="pass" class="loginBox" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['pass']))echo $_COOKIE['pass']; ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
          <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" class="btn btn-default" <?php callRouter(); if(isset($_SESSION['privilege']))echo "disabled"; ?>/>
          <input type="checkbox" class="checkBoxShodow" name="cookieChk" <?php if(isset($_COOKIE['pass']))echo "checked"; ?> />
          <label class="labelShadow">&nbsp;remember me</label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing your question, its quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand the question correctly, you only need to add an anchor to the form's action like so:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm" action="/index.php#focus-on-section">
```

the anchor can be any element with an `id` on your other page:

```
<div id="focus-on-section">
  more stuff
</div>
```